# Is org.objectweb.asm.commons.LocalVariablesSorter incorrectly optimizing?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to use ASM to wrap a method in a try/finally block.  Specifically, I am extending `org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter` and following the technique described ["Using ASM framework to implement common bytecode transformation patterns"](http://asm.ow2.org/current/asm-transformations.pdf) under "3.2.3 Insert Code before Method Exit".

I am also using `LocalVariablesSorter` (a superclass of `AdviceAdapter`) to add a local variable right at the method start which I use in the finally block.

I have a method that I am attempting to modify with ASM.  The method takes three args and has no locals of its own:

```
class Example {
    public static int f4(int i, long l, int f) {
        return (int) (i + l + f);
    }
}
```

Since my `finally` block may be  an exception handler target, I add a call so `super.visitFrame(F_NEW, ...)`, passing the method parameters.  Since this calls up to the super class, I expect my newLocal to be added to this frame by `LocalVariablesSorter`. But when running this through my ASM pipeline, Java 7 gives me the error `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type in method Example.f4(IJI)I at offset 32`.

Looking at the [source of `LocalVariablesSorter`](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Fcommons%2FLocalVariablesSorter.java), in the `visitFrame` method, I see that it has a boolean `changed` and if not changed, `visitFrame` skips any consideration of any new locals I may be created.  This `changed` boolean appears to only be set when upstream bytecode performs certain operations on variables that have had to be remapped due to using `LocalVariablesSorter` to create new locals (and no such operations occur in the `f4()` method above).

By applying this workaround:

```
       Field field = LocalVariablesSorter.class.getDeclaredField("changed");
       field.setAccessible(true);
       field.setBoolean(this, true);
```

I am able to pass Java 7's verifier.  Also, using the `TraceClassVisitor` ASM utility, I see the difference in the stack map frame just before the start of the finally block:

before:

```
FRAME FULL [I J I] [java/lang/Throwable]
```

after my reflection hack (the new local I am adding is an int):

```
FRAME FULL [I J I I] [java/lang/Throwable]
```

I know I have not shared any of the surrounding code, but my question is more general.  Is this `changed` boolean an erroneous optimization by `LocalVariablesSorter`?  Or is it that I am misusing it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The `LocalVariablesSorter.visitFrame(..)` call doesn't add any locals, it only informs ASM to record information about additional frames. You need to add your locals by calling `LocalVariablesSorter.newLocal(..)`.

Though generally, if you believe you found a bug in ASM, it is better to submit bug report to [ASM issue tracker](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/?group_id=23) and provide test code that would allow to reproduce issue (e.g. a test class and complete transformation).

Comment: It is definitely easy to ask here :)  But I will try to extract a minimal test case.